# How To Check Value Of String

Tags: javascript, css, string, numeric

```
<span id='amount'>0.00000000</span>
<a class='button-withdraw' id='tombolco' href='#'>Checkout</a>

<script>
    var amount = document.getElementById("amount").innerHTML;
    if (amount >= 0.001) {
        document.GetElementById("tombolco").style = "display:block";
    } else {
        document.GetElementById("tombolco").style = "display:none";
    }
</script>
```

Why doesn't my code work? What's wrong with it and how can I solve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
document.GetElementById("tombolco").style = "display:block";
```

That's not the right way. This is

```
document.getElementById("tombolco").style.display = 'block';
```

Also note that it is `getElementById`, not with a capital G. Same with `'none'`,Rest of your code is fine.

**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rq28bap2/)**

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>
var amount = document.getElementById("amount").innerHTML;
if (amount >= 0.001) {
document.getElementById("tombolco").style.display = 'block';
} else {
document.getElementById("tombolco").style.display = 'none;
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

If  you want to assign a CSS string to the element, as you are trying to do, use `style.cssText`:

```
document.getElementById("tombolco").style.cssText = "display:block";
```